# Network Related C# Queries

Tags: c#

Can `PrincipalContext` class which is present under namespace `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`
accept Domainname as IPV6 address.

```
PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,Domainname, null, ContextOptions.Negotiate);
```

We know that it accepts Domain name as IPV4 address. But unsure if it supports IPV6 address

Can someone have knowledge about this?